# Using VSCode Debugger for Jest Tests throws error "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-modules, babel-jest

I have tried so many things, that i might just be making it worse at this stage. There are a lot of related questions, but nothing fixes my issue. I am obviously doing something wrong.

I want to use VSCode debugger with my Jest Tests. I had this working when I was using require & module.export.. switching to ES6 modules with import & export gave me the error "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

I've tried getting it working with babel configurationsm then read now that ES6 modules are supported that we don't need babel. I really don't mind how I get it working.

typical export is like

```
export default function buildIdentifiables(disposals, acquisitions) {
```

typical import (tried with and without .js)

```
import buildIdentifiables from './buildIdentifiables.js'
```

**My package.json**

```
  "name": "cgc-node",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@": "src"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-jest": "^26.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "jest-environment-node": "^26.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": true
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "currency.js": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "mysql": "github:mysqljs/mysql",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "uuid": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

**Launch.json**

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/CGTC/cgc-node/main.js"
        },

        {
          "name": "Jest",
          "type": "node",
          "request": "launch",
          "env": { "NODE_ENV": "test" },
          "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
          "program": "${workspaceRoot}/CGTC/cgc-node/node_modules/.bin/jest",
          "stopOnEntry": false,
          "args": ["--config=${workspaceRoot}/CGTC/cgc-node/package.json"],
          "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"],
          "console": "internalConsole",
          "sourceMaps": false,
          "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
          // "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node"
        }
    ]
}
```

Error message
[image: error message]

File Structure
[image: file structure]

While trying a million things, i ended up with **jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    testEnvironment: "node",
    verbose: true,
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
};
```

and babel.cofig.js

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Let me know if there is anything extra I can post to help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I couldn't quite "fix" my problem (even with the help of someone quite knowledgeable), I had to start again with a clean vanilla repo and just paste my files in.

However, i think a big part of my problem was HOW I opened vscode. I have my main "coding" folder opened (so all projects visible at once) and with a single launch.json file outside of all these projects. As the launch.json file points at a specific directory, i'm not sure if this "global" launch file can work.

Maybe there is a way to still open up the folder with all projects, where each project has it's own launch.json file, but I haven't gotten it working yet.

Instead, it works when I navigate to the root directory of your project and `code .` with its own launch.json file at project root.

```
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Jest Tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--inspect-brk",
        "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
        "--runInBand"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "node-jest-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "yarn jest"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0"
  },

  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.2.2",

  }
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = (api) => {
  api.cache(false);

  const presets = [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: {
          esmodules: true,
          node: "current",
        },
      },
    ],
  ];

  return {
    presets,
  };
};
```

Comment: I had the same problem when trying to debug a Typescript Jest test inside a monorepo with multiple sub-packages. My mistake was starting VSCode in the root folder. If I instead open just the sub-package folder that I want to work in, then the problem goes away, and I can debug.